# Using Amixer to control volume

Tags: 14.04, volume-control

I'm running 14.04, and I was told I could use `amixer` to control volume via the command line. For example, to mute sound you would use

```
amixer set Master mute
```

The output for me is

```
amixer: Unable to find simple control 'Master',0
```

So I did some man reading and found out I needed to replace Master with the name of my laptop's mixer control. Typing `amixer` returns:

```
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
```

So naturally, I enter `amixer set IEC958 mute` but all I get is

```
Simple mixer control 'IEC958',0
  Capabilities: pswitch pswitch-joined
  Playback channels: Mono
  Mono: Playback [off]
```

Once again. I've tried `sset` and some other commands but every single one returns the same text. Also, why is there no "Master" or "Speaker" controls? Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 31):

If you want to use `amixer` to control the volume, this should work in a terminal:

```
amixer -D pulse sset Master 0%
```

(0% to mute or use any percentage you like)

To reduce/increase the volume, you can add - or + after % (but that doesn't work to increase the sound beyond 100%).

Comment: Thank you a lot. It works also with `amixer -D pulse set Master mute`

Comment: Why do we supply pulse as a parameter in amixer command?I have noticed if I doesn't supply pulse parameter to amixer command it doesn't work and throws error.

Answer (score 3):

might be possible you use the wrong card.
make sure you use the right card. If you have attached a webcam with mic for example, then it might eat the first slot ;-)

list all cards first:

```
cat /proc/asound/cards
```

for me itlooks like:

```
 0 [Webcam         ]: USB-Audio - Philips SPC 1030NC Webcam
                      Philips CE Philips SPC 1030NC Webcam at usb-orion-ehci.0-1.2, high speed
 1 [Audio          ]: USB-Audio - USB Audio
                      USB Audio at usb-orion-ehci.0-1.5.7, full speed
```

then chose your card. 1st card would be default -c 0, so if you want to chose the 2. card then do:

```
amixer -c 1 sset Master +10
```

Substitute `Master` with the found name including the single quotes after the `Simple mixer control` label in the output.

Comment: I mean (forgot to enter the set): 
amixer -c 1 set Master 100

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to mute my Webcam mic with no success.

Comment: Note the `s` to list all cards... `cat /proc/asound/cards`

Answer (score 3):

I have found 3 useful commands:

`amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%-`

`amixer -D pulse sset Master 5%+`

`amixer -D pulse sset Master toogle`

Other 2 commands:

`amixer -D pulse sset Master mute`

`amixer -D pulse sset Master unmute`

Comment: this worked for me thanks!

Comment: no need for pulse for me. The trick was to do 5%+ and not +5% (which sounds more natural, pun intended). Now looking back at the manual page, I can read indeed that `When plus(+) or minus(-) letter is *appended* after volume value, the volume is incremented or decremented from the current value, respectively.`. Emphasis mine.

Answer (score 0):

```
amixer set IEC958,0 mute
```

You have to specify your card as shown in the amixer output. Use "unmute" instead of "mute" to turn the sound back on again.